# How can i insert only rows to the view created

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized

IN Postgrsql, We have created a materialized view called- orders dataset which contains all the customer order details. Please suggest what is the ideal solution , if i just need to update only the current date and future orders of the customers daily and not the past orders. the past orders of the customers need not be refreshed daily. How shall i achieve this. I mean, only orders of current and future dates to be refreshed and past dates need not be changed/refreshed. How to do this, View / Materialized view.? What type of refresh will help me achieve this.

I tried creating materialized view.

Comment: You cannot do that with a materialized view, only with a table.

Comment: *update only the current date and future orders of the customers daily and not the past orders* If you mean you're holding order details in a table and you want something to only show orders with today's date or later, then both a view and materialized view will do. A simple view with a `where order_date>=current_date` would qualify as *updatable* in the sense that you can `insert`/`update`/`delete` against it. It also continually self-updates in the sense that if the date changes, it'll no longer show orders that are now >=1 day old. Please explain what you meant by *update* and *refresh*.

Comment: You established *which ones* need to be refreshed: only current/today and future. You established *when*: daily. Question is: refreshed *how*? What's the difference between a record of an order for 2 apples before, and after that refresh? If there's some custom logic in the materialized view and you just want to `refresh materialized view` without having to recompute anything older than 1 day, then you either need [`pg_ivm` extension](https://github.com/sraoss/pg_ivm#pg_ivm) to make it incremental, or you need to add the condition based on `current_date` to simply exclude them from the matview

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of your issue:

- You have a materialized view named orders
- This matview contains all customer orders (both past, current and future)
- you want to "update" the matview. I asume you mean refresh...
- your don't want to "update" (refresh) any old orders which have been finalized (probably because of performance)

To give a good answer on this we need to know what exactly the reason for the materialized view is (why is it not a table) and what the setup of the data in the m aterialized view is.

I can imagine a sollution in which you split the data from the materialilzed views in 2 materialized views. Namely all order from current month and onwards, and all orders from prev month and before. Then the "Archived" matview only needs to be refreshed at the start of a new month, and the daily refreshed matview will be performancewise massivly improved.
To keep the same functionality you now have, you can put a view overtop the both of them which just unions them, which can then be called to get the same result.

Footnote: This is based on some assumptions about what you meant as OP since not everything in the question was clear.

Comment: Hiii, thankyou for helping me out .. I am unsure if i have to create a view or materialized view to achieve the functionality i mentioned (that is, refresh/update only current date and future date order records) .

Comment: A matview is just a view, whos data is stored to memory, for performance reasons. Updating a part of a matviewis not possible, since it is described/created from one query. So it is either refreshing the whole view or not refreshing. The only solution you have is to break it up in 2 or more matviews. One with data which is not refreshed (often). And one with data which  refreshes often. Then you can update them at diffrent frequencies, making the heavy lifting (update "archive") much less frequent then the light lifting (update current). With a view you can then "union all" both matviews

Comment: More help requires more informations, such as the queries from the matview, the underlying table structures, information about record frequency, etc.

Comment: thankyou so much.. understood. so i create two matviews.. and a view with a query that does union all of two matviews.. right..??

Comment: thankyou so much.. understood. so i create two matviews (one with old/previous months order records -- with no rules for refreshing and another with current date and future order records --  with rules such as refresh twice or thrce daily) and finally a materialized view again with a query that does union all of  these two matviews.. right..??. this final mat view also to be refreshed twice or thrice daily.